# Failed to connect remote VM. Connection timed out(Failed to connect remote VM. Connection timed out)

Tags: java

Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out

Project -SDK
Connection type - Standard (Socket Attach)
Host: IP address of the SAP server
Port: 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nowhere like enough information in your question to identify the actual cause of your problem (or the fix), but problems like this *typically* occur because:

- you are using the wrong hostname or IP address when connecting to the server
- the server is off
- a firewall is blocking your access to the server
- there is something wrong with the network.

Hope this will give you some ideas about what to look for.

Comment: Thank You so much Stephen. I will try my best.